# How to pass Objects from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm building a mobile app using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile.
It's all single `.html` file with around 10 pages `data-role="page"`
There is a `Updates` page which should fetch the updates from the server (update frequency: everyday)

When user clicks "Updates" this is the strategy:

[image]

I'm using File API of Cordova/Phonegap but I'm having hardtime passing objects from one function to other. Because, this entire File API is working through callbacks. I was expecting, they'll return the objects to me so that I can pass them to other functions. Because of these call backs I feel like I've lost control over the flow of execution. It became haphazard, non-linear.

This is my completely disconnected code:

```
function getUpdate(){
    alert("inside getUpdate");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/updates.jsonp',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(jsonobj){
            var text = '';
            var update = jsonobj[0];
            // I need to pass this `jsonobj` to other functions
            alert('Node nid: ' + update.nid );
            startFileReadingProcess();
        }


    });
}

function startFileReadingProcess() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("updates.json", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    console.log("Got File Entry");          
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail); //<-- I need to pass this fileEntry to fileWriter
}

function gotFile(file){
    console.log("Got File Pointer Success");        
    readAsText(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read Success: Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
    checkContentsEmpty(reader.result, file)
}

function checkContentsEmpty(filecontents, file){
    if(filecontents){
        alert(filecontents);
        var jsonobj = JSON.parse(filecontents);
    }
    else{
        alert("filecontents=null => File is Empty");
    }
}

// This function is duplicate. I've already got gotFileEntry for fileReader. How to avoid this?
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    //I need the fileEntry object, got in above function
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
// I need json update got from the server in this function
writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
    console.log("write success");
};
writer.write( "Some sample text" );
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("Failed to retrieve file: " + error.code);
}
```

Comment: Most of the code is directly taken from http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html. I know its not production ready but I'm just trying to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to save necessary variables as global variables. I mean:

```
var savedFileEntry;

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    console.log("Got File Entry");
    savedFileEntry = fileEntry;
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}
```

Then you can use it anywhere.

UPDATE. You can also try to use $.Deferred

```
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    console.log("Got File Entry");          
    var promise = getFile(fileEntry);
    promise.done(function(result) {
        if (result) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        }
    });
}

function getFile(fileEntry) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        gotFile(file);
        deferred.resolve(true);
    },
    function(error) {
        fail(error);
        deferred.resolve(false);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid this. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: @claws I wonder who votes down correct answer silently, but i updated answer with another option what can be done there. And, by the way, if you organize your code as JS class, than idea with global variable (will be object private field in class) doesn't look like last resort.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I didn't upvote it either. But now I did upvote it.

Comment: @claws i didn't tell that you downvoted it) There are a lot of strange people, you know... I just get a little angry every time they downvote without explanation. And what about question and answer? Which one idea you prefer more?